# How to loop nested json into ul li using ngFor in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a nested json,I need to append that json format into ul li tag using ngFor as per below output format,I can use ngfor loop but I am not getting how to use it.Here is the expected output(hardcoded) in html.Below is the code.

### home.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
  <ul>
    <li class="parentNav">parent1</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul>
        <li>child11<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
        <li>child12<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="parentNav">parent2</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul>
        <li>child2<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="parentNav">parent3</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul>
        <li>child3<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit { 

    nestedjson:any;
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {


     }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.nestedjson = [{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},{"name":"parent3","value":["child3"]}];

} 




}
```

Comment: you want to build a recursive ?

Comment: You should at least try something. Read https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor, and https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#list-heroes-with-ngfor.

Comment: That's not JSON.  JSON is a string.  Your variable `nestedjson` starts with a `[`, which means it's a javascript array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwk8ru?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
  <ul *ngFor="let item of nestedjson">
    <li class="parentNav">parent1</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let child of item.value">{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: on putting ngFor on ul, it throws JIT compilation error. Why is it happening

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the one below. Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-ng-for-nested?file=src/app/app.component.html). Your solution side by side with ngFor.

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
  <ul *ngFor="let parent of nestedJson">
    <li  class="parentNav">{{parent.name}}</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let child of parent.value" >{{child}}<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you have a JSON string, then you will need to use JSON.parse() to get the object in the format above.

Comment: That doesn't generate what the OP wants.

Comment: It does. I copied his html first and it was exactly this. Check stakblitz, I included both.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read the code in the question correctly. Your code generates one `<li class="childData">`per child. The OP wants a single one.

Comment: This is literally what he has posted in his "hardcoded" solution      <ul>
        <li>child11<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
        <li>child12<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
      </ul>

Comment: Yes, and that's not what your code generates. Look in what the OP posted: there is a single `<li class="childData">` after `<li class="parentNav">parent1</li>`. Your code generates one `<li class="childData">` per child.

Comment: True story. Took me a while to get what you meant. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That's very basic. You should try it yourself first.

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
    <ul *ngFor="let nested of nestedjson">
        <li class="parentNav">{{ nested.name }}</li>
        <li class="childData">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let val of nested.value">{{ val }}<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhtnsd

Comment: That doesn't generate what the OP wants.

Comment: That's exactly what he wants.

Comment: No it's not. The OP wants a single `<li class="childData">` for each parent. Your code generates one per child in each parent